# Unable to find oracle stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I'm trying to call a stored procedure from a oracle database and it seems I can't find it as I keep receiving the `No @NamedStoredProcedureQuery was found with that name` error like this one:

```
"message": "No @NamedStoredProcedureQuery was found with that name : GET_POLICY_DATA; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No @NamedStoredProcedureQuery was found with that name : GET_POLICY_DATA",
```

I'm not the one who created the stored procedure but I was able to get its content:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PAP.PAYMENT_HIERARCHY IS

  TYPE TAB_POLICY_LIST IS TABLE OF TPOLICYS.POL_NUM%TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  FUNCTION GET_POLICY_DATA(POLICY_LIST IN TAB_POLICY_LIST)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR;

END PAYMENT_HIERARCHY;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PAP.PAYMENT_HIERARCHY IS

  FUNCTION EXTRACT_POLICY_LIST(POLICY_LIST IN TAB_POLICY_LIST)
    RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    L_POL_LIST VARCHAR2(32767) := NULL;
  BEGIN
    FOR I IN 1 .. POLICY_LIST.COUNT LOOP
      IF L_POL_LIST IS NULL THEN
        L_POL_LIST := '''' || POLICY_LIST(I) || '''';
      ELSE
        L_POL_LIST := L_POL_LIST || ',''' || POLICY_LIST(I) || '''';
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN L_POL_LIST;
  END;

  FUNCTION GET_POLICY_DATA(POLICY_LIST IN TAB_POLICY_LIST)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS

    O_CURSOR   SYS_REFCURSOR;
    L_POL_LIST VARCHAR2(32767);
  BEGIN
    L_POL_LIST := EXTRACT_POLICY_LIST(POLICY_LIST);
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('GET_POLICY_DATA ' || L_POL_LIST);
    OPEN O_CURSOR FOR
      SELECT 
            <FIELD LIST>
        FROM <TABLE_NAME> A
       WHERE INSTR(L_POL_LIST, A.POL_NUM) > 0;
    RETURN O_CURSOR;
  END;

  PROCEDURE INIT_PKG IS
  BEGIN
    NULL;
  END;
BEGIN
  INIT_PKG;
END PAYMENT_HIERARCHY;
```

Here is my entity class:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name = PolicyEntity.FUNCTION_NAME,
        procedureName = PolicyEntity.PROCEDURE_NAME,
        parameters = {
                @StoredProcedureParameter(
                        name = PolicyEntity.PI_POL_NUM,
                        type = String.class,
                        mode = ParameterMode.IN),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(
                        name = PolicyEntity.OUT_POL_NUM,
                        type = List.class,
                        mode = ParameterMode.OUT)
        })
@Entity
public class PolicyEntity {
    
    public static final String FUNCTION_NAME = "GET_POLICY_DATA";

    public static final String PROCEDURE_NAME = "PAP.PAYMENT_HIERARCHY";
    
    public static final String PI_POL_NUM = "PI_POL_NUM";
    
    public static final String OUT_POL_NUM = "PI_POL_NUM";
    
    /** The id. */
    @Id
    public String id;
}
```

And this is the implementation class that executes the query:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class PolicyRepositoryImpl implements PolicyRepository {
    
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    
    @Override
    public String getPolicyData(String policyNo) {
        System.out.println(1);
        StoredProcedureQuery query =
                em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery(
                        PolicyEntity.FUNCTION_NAME);

        System.out.println(2);
        List<String> policyList = new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.println(3);
        policyList.add(policyNo);

        System.out.println(4);
        query.setParameter(PolicyEntity.PI_POL_NUM, policyList);

        System.out.println(5);
        query.execute();

        System.out.println(6);
        try {
            System.out.println(7);
            System.out.println(query.getOutputParameterValue(PolicyEntity.PI_POL_NUM));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(8);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return null;
    }

}
```

By the way, I added those prints to see where it all goes wrong and it already fails when the entity manager calls the procedure. I'm not that familiar in using debuggers.

I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my setup. This is my first time using this approach as I have always used native queries. Any help will be much appreciated

EDIT:

I just learned that the procedure I'm calling was defined under `Packages`. I don't know if that makes any difference but I thought it was worth mentioning

Comment: It looks like your function is in your package and not outside like it is referenced in Java. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: you must use PACKAGE_NAME.PROCEDURE_NAME and PACKAGE_NAME.FUNCTION_NAME to make a reference to those objects

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I'm sorry for asking this but are you referring to the entity? I'm really bad at this I'm sorry

Comment: your code says: FUNCTION_NAME = "GET_POLICY_DATA" , there is no such function in your database. Try to use "PAP.PAYMENT_HIERARCHY.GET_POLICY_DATA" instead

Comment: Oh yeah I already tried that but still got the same error anyway

Comment: which user are you using to connect to the database ? PAP ??

Comment: If you mean user as username for connecting to the database, I'm using PAP_IL

Comment: Does the PAP_IL user have execute privilege on the PAP.PAYMENT_HIERARCHY package?  Try connecting as PAP and doing "grant execute on PAYMENT_HIERARCHY to PAP_IL;"  Then try executing the packaged procedure and/or function from the PAP_IL user.

Comment: Yeah I think it does. Here's a question though, the procedure returns a result set and its possible that it may contain several result sets. I'm looking at the possibility that the way I designed the entity has something to do with my problem